Err 429 opening Word document using Outlook VBA
I have an Outlook macro that opens a todo list in Word to add tasks when a certain category ("todo") is checked.
Lately it has been throwing

Err.Number 429

'OPEN THE TODO FILE
For Each wdDoc In wdApp.Documents
    If wdDoc.Name = strDocName Then
        booAlreadyOpen = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next wdDoc
If booAlreadyOpen = False Then
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strDocPath, Visible:=True)
End If

Err 429 is "too many requests.". I call this macro once or twice a day.
It worked until about two weeks ago. We have not made any changes to our system unless something happened in a pushed-out update, which I also do not recall triggering.
The document I am trying to open (strDocPath) refers to a synced file on my C:drive that is on SharePoint. Others (I think only one person -- only three others have access) also use this document, but the macro is mine alone, so nobody else could be calling it.

VBA error 429 is "ActiveX component can't create object" are you sure that's not what you're getting?  Can you manually open that same file in Word?

Can't create object makes more sense, since that's what I'm trying to do. I do not know where ActiveX comes in however. I can open the word document manually without any problem.

Just a guess, but I'd check whether you have more than one instance of Word running (e.g. via Windows Task Manager -it's possible that something is opening your document in another instance (say "B"), but that your macro is looping through the documents open in instance A - then fails when it tries to open the document because it's already open. If that's the case, it may be difficult to fix in VBA - probably best to try to find out why the document is already open. (ActiveX/COM is the name of the mechanism VBA uses to create/open "objects").
